# Setting up stereo cameras

Tags: linux, video, images, camera, opencv

I am about to set up stereo cameras, and use OpenCV for real-time image and depth processing, the last time I tried, I have bought a pair of uncompressed cameras which the problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781770/capturing-multiple-webcams-uvcvideo-with-opencv-on-linux) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux) happened to me because ALL of my USB ports are connected to one data bus and camera should share its capacity with each other in order to read two frames at the same time!

As the answers in those links, I need to have a camera with MJPEG data format. After I search for suitable cameras meeting my needs and *exist in the market of the area where I live*, I have come to [this](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=55441&ctNode=161) camera, but I've got some questions before I buy it.

#### Questions:

1. Considering that this camera supports 720p HD with MJPEG compression, can I use two of them to get my stereo set up going without any hardware capacity overflow problem(i.e Will the `720p HD` cause me any problems)?
2. What is `Max. Still Image Resolution`? I have googled it, but not sure if the value set for it will or will not cause any problem for me since I have  one data bus on my laptop connected to USB ports.
3. Eventually, do you recommend this camera for my use? please note that these cameras finally will be mounted on a *Raspberry Pi* system.

P.S: I can have [this](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=53211&ctNode=161) type of camera too but and I am sure it will meet my needs but since it does not have `autofocus` capability, I am not sure that this lack of feature will cause me problem at image processing level, considering that a robot(drone) will host these cameras which will operate in random environment, so `autofocus` may be an important feature to have.

Comment: Note: your 3rd question is not [on-topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (asking for a product recommendation). It's not the reason to down vote nor to flag the whole post, still you should consider removing the 3rd question in order to follow the site standards.