# Complex streaming setup problems

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture

**Here is the complete diagram of my streaming setup :**

[image]

---

I have problems linking *PC2* and *PC3*, let me explain.

Capture Cards and Webcams cannot be plugged on the same PC because of [software](https://github.com/tolga9009/elgato-gchd/issues/31) [limitations](https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux), so I must have two PCs, one for each CC+Webcam combination.
As a result, I must stream Webcam1 and CC1 from PC2 to PC3 running *OBS Studio*.

I tried streaming one device using VLC, it works well if I read the stream using VLC but OBS cannot handle it (very, very laggy - 1 or 2 FPS maximum), so I can't imagine streaming two devices...

What are my options to link PC2 and PC3 (2 streams), with minimal lagging and maximum reliability ?

Thanks

---

Also, [ASTER](http://www.ibik.ru/) is a multiseat software which works very well with games.

Comment: PC3 merges the 4 video streams + sounds into a single viewable stream, nicely laid out for viewers to enjoy, this is why I need to send the data from PC2 to PC3. Also, I don't want to load PC1 with encoding or window capturing, this is why I use capture cards. Finally, trying to simplify the setup is definitely the way to go, but I can't find any way to do it even after scratching my head for weeks, and that's why I'm asking

Comment: Well the obvious approach would be to get rid of the multi seat setup. If you run multiple games that run just fine with that setup it's probably easy to split it up. Depending on what streaming service you're using you could just stream normally to individual channels and use something like multitwitch and maybe re stream that on a combined channel. Obviously that is going to cause even more delays than you already got. As for the captures I mentioned I didn't mean to do any of that on PC1 but PC2 & 3. OBS should be fine capturing the VLC window(s).

Comment: There is no game running in PC2 & 3, they are just here to encode and stream whatever is needed. The only PC on which games are run is PC1, which runs two instances of the same games for monitors 1 and 2.
Getting rid of the multi-seat setup is, imo, not a good idea : I would need to buy yet another PC to play and cannot afford the cost (~800€ min! ), and it wouldn't solve any problem as far as I understand

Comment: Did you try to use Windows on PC3 in order to check whenever those bugs don't exist on Windows?